# Удаление среднего символа с++

Tags: c++, символы, предложения

Здравствуйте. Поможет-ли кто-нибудь решить и подробно разобрать код и объяснить?
По учебе задано.
Текст задания:
Дан текст, состоящий из нескольких предложений. Предложения оканчиваются точкой, восклицательным или вопросительным знаками. Из каждого предложения удалить средний символ, если длина предложения нечетна, и два средних символа, если длина четная.

Как я понял, тут надо считать Length до одного из знаков (.!?) и уже в каждом отрезке посчитать кол-во символов и удалить средние. Вот и не пойму, как реализовать. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Да, примерно так. По циклу проходите текст. Сначала указатель на начало строки - это указатель на начало первого предложения. Ищете знак (!?.) - указатель на конец. Разница - это длина, удаляете символ(ы). Далее указатель на начало второго предложения - это первый непробельный символ от конца. Снова ищете знак (!?.) и так далее до конца текста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <signal.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string source = "Hello world ! My name is stackowerflow.";

    std::vector<std::string> tokens = {"!","?","."};

    for(std::string token : tokens){
        size_t pos = source.find(token);
        if( pos != std::string::npos){
            source.erase(pos/2,1);
        }
    }

    std::cout<<source<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, Дейкстра ([EWD](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/)) не ошибся...

Comment: @avp, что ты этим хочешь сказать ?

Comment: То, что такой алгоритм выделения предложений (кстати, ведь может быть и несколько предложений, которые завершаются одним и тем же символом) крайне не эффективен